# numpy array is created on spark driver or executor?

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I am confused where the numpy array is created when I have it run on spark cluster:

```
a = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype="byte")
```

I feel it should be created on driver. But if that is the case, how can we make use of the distributed computing power of spark, in other words, why do we need to use `numpy` on spark if it cannot be distributed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO. numpy will pull data into your driver and may cause OOM if data is beyond memory limit.